# What's the point of Socket.Disconnect(true)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sockets, .net-core, networking

MSDN description:

```
public void Disconnect (bool reuseSocket);
```

> true if this socket can be reused after the current connection is
> closed; otherwise, false.

Where Socket would be reused? C# developer could reuse it (Connect second time) or winsock (linux sockets) would be reused internally in OS?
I thought I could reuse it manually in C# code. For example: I have to handle many remote socket connections to different EP, so I could use `ObjectPool<Socket>` or smth, take socket from pool, connect it, do stuff, then Disconnect(true) it (if no SocketExceptions) and return it to pool for future reuse.

But I looked into Source code (.NET 5) and discovered the following:

**Socket.cs:**

```
public void Disconnect(bool reuseSocket)
        {
            ...

            errorCode = SocketPal.Disconnect(this, _handle, reuseSocket);

            ...
        }
```

**SocketPal.cs:**

```
internal static SocketError Disconnect(Socket socket, SafeSocketHandle handle, bool reuseSocket)
        {
            handle.SetToDisconnected();

            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            return reuseSocket ?
                socket.ReplaceHandle() :
                SocketError.Success;
        }
```

So if `reuseSocket == true` will be executed `socket.ReplaceHandle()`

**Socket.cs**

```
internal SocketError ReplaceHandle()
        {
            // Copy out values from key options.

... STUFF FOR COPYING SOCKET OPTIONS ...
    
            // Then replace the handle with a new one
            SafeSocketHandle oldHandle = _handle;
            SocketError errorCode = SocketPal.CreateSocket(_addressFamily, _socketType, _protocolType, out _handle);
            oldHandle.TransferTrackedState(_handle);
            oldHandle.Dispose();
            if (errorCode != SocketError.Success)
            {
                return errorCode;
            }

            // And put back the copied settings.  

... STUFF FOR COPYING SOCKET SETTINGS ...

            return SocketError.Success;
        }
```

So we can see this line `SocketError errorCode = SocketPal.CreateSocket(_addressFamily, _socketType, _protocolType, out _handle);` Which is just create a new socket. We can find the same line in the Socket.cs ctor()

It turns out that it makes little sense to `Socket.Disconnect(true)`? And it makes no performance improvements?