Can Client use the same Socket object to reconnect to remote after disconnect
Maybe the simple answer is no, a new socket object must be created each time... but my situation is.

Client creates socket and uses ConnectAsync to connect to remote server
ConnectAsync Completed event runs and Connection starts
Connection to Server is forcibly severed (SocketException)


[Unattainable? GOAL] Reconnect to the server using the same Socket object

I know using socket.close() and then recreating the socket allows me to reconnect the server. But is that cleanest/proper way of reconnecting to the server and why? Otherwise is there a better/proper way to reconnect using the same socket?
I have searched Stackoverflow and google all over the place and the closest I got was that a reconnect is possible with a different endpoint which doesnt fit my usecase.
I have tried the following
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);
connectArgs.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(myIP, myPortNo);
connectArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(ConnectCallback);
socket.ConnectAsync(connectArgs);

... After Forcibly Disconnected

// This does not get run because the forcibly connection cut exception sets Connected to false. 
// And Shutdown/Disconnect will throw an exception if the socket is not Connected.
if (socket.Connected) 
{
  socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
  socket.Disconnect(true); // this is the reuse bool property.
}
// socket.close() // calling this disposes the object, can no longer connect with it again so this is also out

socket.ConnectAsync(connectArgs); //<- immediately returns false

Is there a way to gracefully reset this socket object without resetting to a new socket instance so that I can use the ConnectAsync command again and have it work like the first time?

The short answer is "no" - Sockets are not reusable. But why is that a problem?

@Dai I was told to investigate the MSDN and confirm the proper way of doing things, but the MSDN is sort of lacking in explanation of those details while leaving glimmers of hope that sockets CAN be reused when using disconnec(true) or setting the similar socket option. The other potential issue is that recreating sockets supposedly use lots of resources. Including potentially leaving behind lots of TIME_WAIT ports in use, I've confirmed the TIME_WAIT clogging is not the case though with testing though SyncSent does not goto TimeWAIT. But the wasteful resource one is more difficult to confirm.

On a side note, Forcibly closed exceptions by the server also does not goto TIME_WAIT for whatever reason. (Server is a Windows service that I close with taskkill /f /pid to generate the exception)

...could you switch to UDP instead?

@Dai The server is not my code or program so unfortunately not.

@Dai On a tangent, if Sockets are not reuseable, what is the point or usecase of the reuse option?

There's a whole article about SO_REUSEADDR + SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE and it explains it's for security reasons (i.e. preventing another socket from butting-in on your connection), not performance or reducing overhead:

Have you read the article about designing for fewer connects?

No wow, extremely interesting articles for both. So ReuseAddr is for extremely rare situations and should be left off or default(off) as it basically allows for socket/port hijacking. What a confusing and incomplete name lol. In the middle of reading the other which looks promising as a official practice/proper way of doing things. Thanks so much!

I guess your real question is why the remote side is not shutting down correctly with a normal FINACK.

@Charlieface Sorry, not true, the remote side does shutdown normally in regular situations, but we had an issue where if the connection is forcibly killed for whatever reason the client would stall out trying to reuse the socket, so in my fix/investigation/tests I had to recreate the forcibly closed exception, and during that I was also tasked to investigate proper socket usage, with why explanations.

I did some more sleuthing and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935653/whats-the-point-of-socket-disconnecttrue in which someone tracks the code for disconnect true and finds that it just recopies socket settings/resets the handle so the socket can be reused (like creating a new socket). I guess SO_REUSEADDR and disconnect(resuseSocket) is different. But disconnect can only be called on a Connected Socket, it cannot fix a disconnected and/or exceptioned socket...

Either way, why can't you just dump the socket on error and reconnect with a new one? If what you are saying is true then forced disconnectes are rare and shouldn't cause much of an issue with socket reuse. Why does it have to be the same socket?

@Charlieface The question is CAN a socket be reused. Meaning the answer is either "No, and this is why", or "Yes, and this is how". The WHY I didn't just use a new socket is because I am unfamiliar with the conventions and best practices of socket usage and was told to find that out because of the potential pitfalls of wasted/lingering sockets/ports + wasted resource usage. So It didn't NEED to be the same socket, but just needed justification to create and use a new socket. Honestly I was fine with a new socket until I was told to find out why.

No, the socket cannot be reused after a connection abort (a RST packet or a network failure). You need to close the socket and open a new one.
The WinSock docs state that if a connection reset error occurs then the socket is unusable.

WSAECONNRESET: The virtual circuit was reset by the remote side executing a hard or abortive close. The application should close the socket as it is no longer usable. On a UPD-datagram socket this error would indicate that a previous send operation resulted in an ICMP "Port Unreachable" message.

Also:

WSAECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, the host or remote network interface is disabled, or the remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket). This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

The only time you can reuse a socket after the connection has ended is if you use Disconnect/DisconnectAsync, this is not normal usage.
I strongly suggest you use TcpClient instead of raw sockets, as that can manage all the connecting and closing of sockets for you. Or even an existing higher level protocol, such as HTTP, gRPC or SignalR, because writing a TCP protocol is fraught with pitfalls.

Thank you very much. I do have 1 question though, Winsock vs System.Net.Socket, how closely they are linked?  You and another person referenced Winsock, but the Socket MSDN doesn't. Is Socket just wrapper/interface for winsock? Or are they different?

Pretty much yeah, it's a wrapper for the OS's native Berkley Sockets API, which in Windows' case is Winsock. You may find that other OSs are different.
